# Server keeps running this: —log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log —pid-file=/var/r un/mysql/mysqld

Tags: mysql, linux, server, debian

I have a Debian 8.3 server. And for some reason mysql keeps running this all the time.

What exactly is it? Is it an error, and why does it run so often?

Is it possible to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please check this file **/var/log/mysql/error.log** for exact reason. If you are unable to find, please post the screenshot of that.

Comment: @ReddiRajendraP We had this error: `160317 9:17:09 [Warning] IP address '113.108.21.16' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution`